# Compilation Error At RunTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, compiler-errors

I am attempting to bind a drop down list to query results, I thought I had everything set-up as I should, but before my page ever loads I get an error thrown.  This is the error that I get

Compilation Error

Description:

> An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to
>   service this request. Please review the following specific error
>   details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message:

> CS1061: 'ASP.pages_firstloaded_aspx' does not
>   contain a definition for 'ddlMembers_SelectedIndexChanged' and no
>   extension method 'ddlMembers_SelectedIndexChanged' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'ASP.pages_firstloaded_aspx' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here is the more detailed info:

```
<div class="WhiteBackgroundForDataGrids">
  <font class="BoldTextBlack">Member Names:</font>
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlMembers" CssClass="DropDownLists" 
        Width="120px" onselectedindexchanged="ddlMembers_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

But in my C# code behind I have this (which I thought is what it's searching for)

```
protected void ddlMembers_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

EDIT ---
Even after adding the event handlers to the SelectedIndexChanged it still presents the same error.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code behind, is the following:

```
protected void ddlMembers_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Since it is an Event Handler, you'll want to ensure the control can send the data and context.

Comment: Did you change your front end to match the backend?  I can't replicate.

Comment: Yes, frontend has been altered to mirror the backend.

Comment: You sure, your front end doesn't show `OnSelectedIndexChanged`.